# Establecer el valor de un asp.net dropdownlist con javascript en un content page

Tags: javascript, html, asp

Tengo la siguiente funcion de javascript:

```js
 function tipodepsolicitante_event() {
            var e = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cbotipodepositantes");
            var d = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if (d == "ER") {
                document.getElementById('<%= cbotipodocumentosolicitante.ClientID %>').selectedindex = 1;
                document.getElementById('<%= cbotipodocumentosolicitante.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('<%= cbopaisresidenciasolicitante.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                
            } else {
                document.getElementById('<%= cbotipodocumentosolicitante.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('<%= cbopaisresidenciasolicitante.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Ésta se ejecuta en el evento: `onchange` de otro `dropdownlist`, esto si funciona ya que al ejecutar la función sí se deshabilitan los controles: `cbotipodocumentosolicitante` y `cbopaisresidenciasolicitante`, pero el `.selectedindex` en la primera linea no funciona.

He probado con muchas funciones para seteo de datos que encontré en internet pero nada funciona.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: A cual primera línea te refieres?

Comment: ¿quizás la "i" de selectedindex tenga que estar en mayúscula?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el error es debido a un fallo tipográfico, y no será de gran utilidad a usuarios futuros.

Comment: A esta me refiero: "document.getElementById('<%= cbotipodocumentosolicitante.ClientID %>').selectedindex = 1;"

Answer (score 3):

Lo tienes todo en minusculas, la propiedad selectedIndex lleva la I en mayuscula, prueba cambiar esto y el valor debe ir en comillas dobles.

```
document.getElementById('<%= cbotipodocumentosolicitante.ClientID %>').selectedIndex = "1";
```

Comment: Las comillas pueden ser dobles o simples, en JavaScript es indistinto.

Comment: es case sensitive el selectedIndex? , voy a probar y les comento, gracias :D

Comment: Nope, no funciona, he visto que el dropdown si cambia el índice escogido, pero no se refleja en el texto del dropdown, se debe hacer algun tipo de refresh?